# issue with top_n_rank full text search

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, ranking-functions

This is about `top_n_by_rank` parameter of full text search.

I have a query, suppose:

```
SELECT *
FROM Publisher p 
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(Publisher, Name, @searchText, 100) PublisherSearch
           ON  p.Id = PublisherSearch.[Key]
ORDER BY PublisherSearch.[Rank]
```

Here, I have given `top_n_by_rank = 100`.
This should give me the top ranked 100 records.
But I am getting only 61 records.
When I remove the `top_n_rank` param, it gives me more than 1000 records.

My question is, does the `top_n_by_rank` parameter search only on the first 100 records OR
does it search on all the records and get only the first 100 of the search results?

Comment: What happens when you remove the INNER JOIN and run just the FREETEXTTABLE query like so - SELECT * from FREETEXTTABLE(Publisher, Name, @searchText, 100)? The MSDN article on FREETEXTTABLE states that "if top_n_by_rank is combined with other parameters, the query could return fewer rows than the number of rows that actually match all the predicates."

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your actual question:

> does the top_n_by_rank parameter search only on the first 100 records OR does it search on all the records and get only the first 100 of the search results.

is: `top_n_by_rank` should tell SQL Server to check **all** records and select in the result only `top_n_by_rank` number of the best matching ones.

It's not like plain `SELECT TOP * FROM table`, it pays attention to the record's matching Rank.

Here is what MSDN doc on [FREETEXTTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx#Anchor_1) says about it:

> top_n_by_rank
>   Specifies that only the **nhighest ranked matches**, in descending order, are returned. Applies only when an integer value, n, is specified. If top_n_by_rank is combined with other parameters, the query could return fewer rows than the number of rows that actually match all the predicates. top_n_by_rank allows you to increase query performance by recalling only the most relevant hits.